# BRAVIA Engine 2 after rooting

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia SP running jelly bean 4.1. I wish to root my device using the Doomlord exploit and run kitkat 4.4. But will that affect the working of the Bravia Engine 2 in my device in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bravia engine would need to be included in the new ROM you are installing. It is a software screen enhancement.

http://allenramos.blogspot.ie/2013/05/enhance-your-android-phones-display-w.html?m=1

> The Sony Mobile BRAVIA Engine 3 is a video enhancement program for Sony phones. It uses filters and algorithms to create a clearer and more contrasted picture and an overall smoother experience.

Alternatively there are often flashable zip file mods for the bravia engine for different devices.

Comment: I recently upgraded to Android 6.0.1 with Cyanogenmod 13. I also flashed Bravia Engine 4
(http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/recompeliren-bravia-engine-x-reality-t3141461)
as per the link mentioned here. But I don't see any changes even though the developers say that it worked for Xperia SP.